# single sign on for asp.net and sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I have an asp.net application which signs users in manually. The custom authentication procedure checks several data sources (DB, AD, MF, etc.) and finally sets a forms authentication ticket for the user, if she is successfully authenticated.

I want to share this ticket with sharepoint 2010. I will not be signing in through sharepoint, so there is no need for authentication procedure to caried out on the sharepoint side. (and thus no need, as far as I can see, to define a provider, etc.)

I have tried using claims-based authentication on the sharepoint side, but don't really know how to set it up, since I do the authentication manually on the asp.net application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reviewing "[A Guide to Claims-Based Identity and Access Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx#2ndEdition)" from Microsoft's patterns and practices group. It includes chapters for both web applications and SharePoint 2010.

Comment: I was looking to just share auth cookies, but I can see now that a custom STS on the asp.net side would be the most pain-less way to go. Thank you.